# How to custom draw a cursor handle on MS Chart

Tags: c#, mschart, custom-draw

Can anyone tell me if it is possible to custom draw a cursor handle (can't think of a better word for this) as shown in the image below? I have marked it in red circle.

[image]

The aqua coloured inverted triangle can be dragged left or right between two ends of the chart to move the cursor. I am not sure if the control used in the image above is MSChart but wondering if we can do it in MS chart. The difficulty I am having is finding out exact location of cursor because it is relative to the chart area only and the handle I want to draw is outside the chart area. How do I convert chart area location to outside coordinates?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes is is possible to create such a [`Chart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) but not by drawing on it yourself, please..!

Both the line and the triangle are [`Annotations`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.annotationcollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), namely a [`LineAnnotation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.lineannotation%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and a [`PolygonAnnotation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.polygonannotation%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

A `LineAnnotation` supports being dragged around out of the box if you set `AllowMoving = true`. So they don't relly need a handle.. The `PolygonAnnotation` is best synch'ed with the `LineAnnotation`. Both usually are positioned in the coordinates of the `XAxis`, which looks like `DateTime` in your example, or by setting the data point they sit on..

If you need more help with your code, show how you create the `Chart` and I can try to help, `Charts` are powerful but a little tricky..